# How to raise Google NewsApi limit from 100 results per request? How can I get more results?

Tags: javascript, google-api, fetch

Like in title someone know how get more articles than 100 ? 
totalResults sometimes is > 4000  why i can get max 100 ?

Comment: Limit is set, I am sure they have an offset parameter "page " to make more calls to get the next 100.

Comment: if the api provides pagination - you should be able to get "next" pages by increasing offset

Comment: Can you provide your code for your request?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question but instead is a question about a vendor’s policy for their API that only the vendor can answer, and others here can only speculate about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest that there a restriction in NewsApi
https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines
[image]

For example:
you have next link

```
https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=API_KEY
```

as a result you get next json

```
{
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 20,
-"articles": [
-{
-"source": {
"id": "the-new-york-times",
"name": "The New York Times"
},
...
```

with totalResults parameter.

You need to iterate through pages increment **page** (look at documentation)
param.

upd.

page param in url like this:
https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&page=1&apiKey=API_KEY

Comment: thanks but how use this param ?

Comment: check upd. in answer

Answer (score 0):

Often APIs are limited to a max amount of returned data sets. This is to ensure a controlled behavior. If the API providers let the total results up to the user, they would leave a big uncertainty about the performance of the API.

Who really needs more than the max amount of results is often able to do so by following a “next” link in the API response header, to load the next 100 results.

Additionally the providers often control the requests per second per user to prevent extrem workload of their app.